# How to reduce the size of Microsoft Office installation (updates)?

Tags: microsoft-office, updates, disk-space

In 2014 Microsoft has released several updates for its Office 2013 suite:

- these updates are huge: **~1 GB / update / month**
- Microsoft proposes updates for some Office **components that are not even installed** (e.g. OneDrive, OneNote, Lync, Outlook in my case)
- the updates are **kept on the system drive** (in order to be able to remove them later)
- and finally the updates for the same components are **not merged**, so in a few months they can really eat up quite some gigabytes on the drive.

Well, I can imagine better usage for my SSD...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since turning off the updates is not a wise choice, my solution is to reinstall the whole Office from time to time using an **installer that already includes all of the updates**.

A few days ago I have freed up **5 GB** this way (my previous Office installation was in November 2013).

Note: if you cannot get such an installer you can always **slipstream** your own version with the latest updates:

- http://www.howto-outlook.com/otherprograms/slipstreamoffice2013sp.htm

Comment: We expect more then a link to a website here at Superuser

Comment: I'm glad to hear that slipstreaming offers some relief.  We have a bunch of computers gradually filling up their SSDs with the updates.